# Angular: Ngx-Translate Translate Service not changing language dynamically

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, primeng, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate to support internationalization in my Angular App. My application supports 2 languages - en and zh. I want to provide the option to switch to default language (en) dynamically if the user is using zh language. The menu where I am inserting this option is created via the primeng/api MenuItem. I use the command property of MenuItem to fire the event to change language as in code below.

```js
options: MenuItem[];
this.options = [
  {
    label: "Set default language",
    command: event => this.langChange()
  }]

langChange() {
  this.translate.use("en");
}
```

Using this translates instantly my text which uses the translate directive from zh to en but the text which is subscribed through translate service doesn't gets translated instantly from zh to en. I tried using translate.stream instead of translate.get but there was no change.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in [ngx-translate for Angular9+](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1187). I believe this happens because of missing i18n json files path in the lazy loaded modules. As a work around I reloaded all my supported languages in the app component `constructor()`:

**app.component.ts**

```js
constructor(
  private translate: TranslateService
) {
  const lng = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
  this.translate.setDefaultLang(lng);
  this.translate.use(lng);
  const supportedLangs = ["en", "zh", "fr", "tr", "ar"];
  supportedLangs.forEach((language) => {
    this.translate.reloadLang(language);
  });
}
```

After that you can use or change the app language dynamically in any component like you have already done:

```js
langChange() {
  this.translate.use("en");
}
```

This worked for me.